# Getting "The operation is insecure" error when adding tinymce via tinyMCE.EditorManager.execCommand( 'mceAddControl',false, newId);

Tags: javascript, tinymce

**EDIT: See my answer for the discovered issue and solution. It was due to iframe calling context despite being the same domain**

I cannot figure out why this error is occurring. I am going through these steps:

1. Remove the tinyMCE editor
2. Change the textarea's id
3. add tinymce editor to that textarea with its new id

**CODE**

```
//Remove the tinyMCE editor for this text area (CHANGING TO "true" DOESN't HELP)
tinyMCE.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false, myTextArea.id );


//Change the id
myTextArea.id = newId;

//Add a tiny mce editor  (CHANGING TO "true" DOESN't HELP)
tinyMCE.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddControl',false, newId);
```

The last one throws the error `the operation is insecure`. Why? How do I fic this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing a similar problem, here's what the issue was and how I solved it:

**THE ISSUE**

1. I was submitting a form to an iframe **of the same domain** (because it had a file input, I couldn't use ajax)
2. The iframe then called a method in the parent window to let it know it was done: `window.parent.myObject.handleResponse( {} );`
3. In the method `handleResponse` I was removign adn adding tinymce editors.

The problem is that tinymce creates its own iframes, so even though it was the same origin/domain and *not* cross-origin, the browser (Firefox) was rejecting it as an insecure operation for a child frame to call a parent window's method that does something in another iframe. Despite being the same domain for all of them, the calling context did not allow this.

**THE SOLUTION**

1. Prior to submitting the form to the iframe, start a "watcher" via `setInterval` that checks for a response value to be set.
2. Have the `window.parent.myObject.handleResponse( {} );` simply set that response value
3. When the watcher (which was started in the parent window's context) sees the variable has been set, it can alter all the tinymce editors.